# Executing FART.exe (find and replace text) commands on remote server through SSH

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, replace, ssh, find

I'm executing a batch file on a remote server from our build server (Jenkins) through SSH. The batch file uses `fart.exe` commands to find and replace text. I have placed the `fart.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32` and I'm invoking it as `C:\windows\system32\fart.exe` in the batch file.

The command works perfectly fine oin the remote server, but when invoking through SSH I get an error in the Jenkins log as:

> ```
> '"C:\windows\system32\fart.exe"' is not recognized as internal or external command.
> ```

This is the only error I'm getting and the other commands successfully execute in the batch script. Both of the servers are Windows Server 2012 R2.

I tried adding the path to system variable but it didn't work.

This is how the Fart.exe is used in the batch script.

> ```
> for /R "%BACKUP_SOURCE%" %%G in (%ConfigFile%) do (
> "C:\windows\system32\fart.exe" "%%G" %PlaceHolder% %AppPath%
> ```
>
> )
>
> ### Invoking From Jenkins

[image: Invoking From Jenkins SSH]
I don't think the way i invoke the batch script do matter, because it is done trough the Jenkins SSH plugin. The batch script get invoked successfully. The error i get is from when executing the Fart.exe

I tried invoking a different command of an exe located in the same path, and that is successfully invoked. so i guess the issue is isolated to FART.EXE.

Comment: i have configured the administrator account in SSH in the target server. So  Jenkins uses the administrator account to connect.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of this batch file, and show how you're invoking it through ssh.

Comment: Jenkins also has a "execute script" feature. Put your .bat call here instead